# SQL union of two tables with different columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to get one result set of rows back from two tables with different column names, one line per line in each table.

Result should look like this, blanks can be null, team_id in 2nd half comes from coach_id:

```
-----------------------------------------
player_id | team_id | score | improvement
-----------------------------------------
11          20         5
11          21         4
12          22         2
12          23         2
11          20                   5
11          21                   6
12          21                   5
13          23                   10
```

Here's the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE coaches
    (`id` int, `team_id` int)
;

INSERT INTO coaches
    (`id`, `team_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 20),
    (2, 21),
    (3, 22),
    (4, 23)
;

CREATE TABLE players
 (`id` int, `player_id` int);


INSERT INTO players
(`id`, `player_id`)
VALUES
(1,11),
(2,12),
(3,13),
(4,14)
;
CREATE TABLE games
    (`id` int, `player_id` int, `team_id` int, `score` int)
;

INSERT INTO games
    (`id`, `player_id`, `team_id`, `score`)
VALUES
    (1, 11, 20, 5),
    (2, 11, 21, 4),
    (3, 12, 22, 2),
    (4, 12, 23, 2)
;

CREATE TABLE sessions
    (`id` int, `player_id` int, `coach_id` int, `improvement` int)
;

INSERT INTO sessions
      (`id`, `player_id`, `coach_id`, `improvement`)
VALUES
    (1, 11, 1, 5),
    (2, 11, 2, 6),
    (3, 12, 2, 5),
    (4, 13, 4, 10)
;
```

Tried this, but it wasn't really close:

```
SELECT tweets.player_id
      ,tweets.team_id
      ,follows.coach_id 
FROM tweets FULL OUTER JOIN follows ON (1 = 0);
```

Comment: What you've tried so far ?

Comment: Nothing I've tried has really been close.
SELECT
  tweets.player_id, tweets.team_id, follows.coach_id
  FROM
  tweets
  FULL OUTER JOIN follows
  ON (1 = 0);

Comment: Quoted identifiers using a backtick are invalid for Postgres are you sure you are using Postgres? That look more like MySQL.

Comment: I was trying to set up a simple example from SQLfiddle. I will ultimately be using Postgres

Comment: SQLFiddle supports Postgres as well

Comment: While this question is "easy" because effectivly the tables differ in only 2 colums and have few colums, there solutions/answer do not scale well. The term actually to look at here is `OUTER JOIN` (as in https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6997/what-is-outer-union-and-why-is-it-partially-compatible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nulnullry this

```
 SELECT player_id
    ,team_id
    ,score
    ,NULL AS improvement
FROM games
UNION All
SELECT sessions.player_id
    ,coaches.team_id
    ,NULL AS score
    ,sessions.improvement
FROM sessions
INNER JOIN coaches ON coaches.id = sessions.coach_id
```

Comment: then try null as score

Comment: Have you tested it in your environment ? I don't think so because   `UNION` wont help you to get the exact result so you need to use `UNION ALL`

Comment: How can I **scale** this solution? Imagine that there are 4 columns that are particluar to the `UNION` or even 100, should this imply that the query has to insert 100 `NULL AS` columns?  In addition all selected colums need manual naming, how would the `SELECT *` wildcard work even?

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
select player_id
     , team_id
     , score
     , cast(null as int) as improvement 
from games 
union all 
select s.player_id
     , c.team_id
     , cast(null as int) as score
     , s.improvement 
from sessions as s 
join coaches as c 
    on s.coach_id = c.id 
order by score
```

should work