# Postgresql: append two tables with different columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, append, time-series

I would like to append one table to the other; both tables may have different columns. The result should be a table with all columns and where values do not exist, it should be a missing observation. The data are time series - which I am getting from different sources due to time span constraints - so I need to "stack" them on each other, but it could be that one or the other column is added or dropped off.

As there is a little overlap in the rows I am looking for a solution that would take the data of first table. The problem is then for those column not existing in table 1, they wouldn't exist either when I pick table 1 over table 2.

Current solution is to cut-off table 2 so there is no overlap.

table 1:

```
date        AA    BB    CC    DD
20100101     9    10    11    12
20100102    10    11    12    13
```

table 2:

```
date        AA    BB    CC    EE    FF
20100102                99    99    10
20100103    11    12    13    14    10
20100104    12    13    14    15    11
```

and the result should be

```
date        AA    BB    CC    DD    EE    FF
20100101     9    10    11    12    
20100102    10    11    12    13    99    10
20100103    11    12    13          14    10
20100104    12    13    14          15    11
```

So I do not in fact have anything to "join" on as suggested here: [SQL union of two tables with different columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764499/sql-union-of-two-tables-with-different-columns)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`coalesce` function may be used like in the following :

```
select coalesce(t1.date,t2.date) date, 
       coalesce(t1.aa,t2.aa) aa, 
       coalesce(t1.bb,t2.bb) bb,        
       coalesce(t1.cc,t2.cc) cc, 
       t1.dd,
       t2.ee, 
       t2.ff       
  from table1 t1 full outer join table2 t2 on ( t1.date = t2.date );
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b9a02/8)

Comment: thanks @Barbaros Özhan. Somehow this gives me an error that t2.ee and t2.ff tables do not exist. Maybe I should have mentioned that I am using Python to transmit the query.

Comment: @eternity1 you're welcome. I've considered them as columns of table2.

Comment: in normal sql it seems to work, but in python -> postgres it tells me for every t2.* variable that this does not exist... I have now done the workaround by creating empty columns in t1 such that both columns match